# boost::spirit recursive imperative c++ grammar: BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT fails

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I've been working on a grammar to parse imperative statements (if/else/do/while/for/switch etc.) in c++. All other statements are kept as strings.
I'm currently only testing with if/else (though other statements should work analogous in a variant).
Unfortunately I get a compile time error:

> Error 1   error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<
>   someSeqNode,std::allocator<*Ty>>' to 'boost::fusion::vector<
>   someSeqNode, boost::fusion::void*, boost::fusion::void_,
>   boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_,
>   boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_,
>   boost::fusion::void_> &'
>
> > on line 80 (closing bracket of BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT for ifElseStruct)

The only other questions I found regarding compile issues with BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT and attribute propagation were on structs with only one member or otherwise incompatible attributes between adapted struct and a rule.

It seems to fail on adapting ifElseStruct.ifContent but I don't get why. Resolving the typedef it really is just vector< variant< ifElseStruct, string>>.

Is the recursion the problem? If so, how do I solve this?

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3

#pragma region INCLUDE_STUFF
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
//boost includes for parser and some collection types (e.g. tuple)
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/boost_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_raw.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include "vectorStreamOp.h"//overload stream operator << for std::vector -> for BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#pragma endregion INCLUDE_STUFF

#pragma region NAMESPACE_STUFF
//to shorten calls fruther down
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using boost::spirit::qi::parse;
using boost::optional;
using phx::ref;
using phx::at_c;
using qi::char_;
using qi::lexeme;
using qi::_1;
using qi::lit;
using qi::alnum;
using qi::alpha;
using qi::space;
using qi::raw;
using qi::as_string;
#pragma endregion NAMESPACE_STUFF

#pragma region STRUCT_STUFF
/*later make this variant with all impStatementVariants -> either make this a vector to have sequences on all levels or make imperativeCpp derive from this
-> typedef variant<
recursive_wrapper<ifElseStruct>,
recursive_wrapper<switchStruct>,
recursive_wrapper<forStruct>,
recursive_wrapper<whileStruct>,
recursive_wrapper<doWhileStruct>
*/
struct ifElseStruct;
typedef boost::variant<ifElseStruct, string> someSeqNode;

struct ifElseStruct
{
    string ifCond;
    vector<someSeqNode> ifContent;
    optional<vector<someSeqNode>> elseContent;

    //for BOOST DEBUG
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const ifElseStruct& var) {
        stream << "ifCond: " << var.ifCond << "   ifContent: " << var.ifContent << endl << "elseContent:" << var.elseContent;
        return stream;
    }
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    ifElseStruct,
    (string, ifCond)
    (vector<someSeqNode>, ifContent)
    (optional<vector<someSeqNode>>, elseContent)
    )
#pragma endregion STRUCT_STUFF

#pragma region GRAMMAR_STUFF
    //GRAMMAR for flowcontrol (branching and looping)
    template<typename Iterator, typename Skipper> struct imperativeGrammar :qi::grammar<Iterator, vector<someSeqNode>(), Skipper>
{
    imperativeGrammar() : imperativeGrammar::base_type(startRule)
    {
        startRule = *(recursiveImpCpp | nestedSomething); //vector<variant<ifElseStruct(), string>>
        recursiveImpCpp = ifElseNormalRule.alias() /*| switchRule | whileRule | forRule ...*/;

        //attr: ifElseStruct containing-> string, vector<someSeqNode>, optional<vector<someSeqNode>>
        ifElseNormalRule = lit("if")>> '(' >> condition >> ')' >> ifElseContent >> -(lit("else") >> ifElseContent);

        condition = *~char_(")");//TODO: replace with nestedSomething rule
        ifElseContent = ('{' >> startRule >> '}') /*| singleStatement*/;

        singleStatement = !recursiveImpCpp >> (qi::as_string[*~char_(";")] >> qi::as_string[char_(';')]);
        nestedSomething = !recursiveImpCpp >> qi::as_string[*~char_("(){}")]
            >> -(raw['(' >> nestedSomething >> ')']) >> -(raw['{' >> nestedSomething >> '}'])
            >> !recursiveImpCpp >> qi::as_string[*~char_("(){}")];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((startRule)(ifElseNormalRule)(ifElseContent))
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, vector<someSeqNode>(), Skipper> startRule;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ifElseStruct(), Skipper> recursiveImpCpp;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ifElseStruct(), Skipper> ifElseNormalRule;

    qi::rule<Iterator, string(), Skipper> condition;
    qi::rule<Iterator, vector<someSeqNode>(), Skipper> ifElseContent;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), Skipper> nestedSomething;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), Skipper> singleStatement;

    /*qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> forRule;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> switchCaseBreakRule;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> whileRule;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> doWhileRule;*/
};
#pragma endregion GRAMMAR_STUFF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of issues.

1. Like the comment said, don't use [using-directives](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives); they land you in trouble
2. if all you want to concatenate all source strings in `nestedSomething` then, just wrap it all in a `raw[]` (or `as_string[raw[...]]` but that's not even necessary), e.g.

   ```
   nestedSomething = !recursiveImpCpp >> qi::raw[*~char_("(){}")
       >> -('(' >> nestedSomething >> ')')
       >> -('{' >> nestedSomething >> '}')
       >> !recursiveImpCpp >> *~char_("(){}")];
   ```
3. that rule is broken in the sense that it will match an empty string. This makes the grammar never end (it will match an "infinite" amount of empty `nestedSomething`). You will have to decide on some non-optional part. Here's a brute-force fix:

   ```
   qi::raw[...] [ qi::_pass = px::size(qi::_1) > 0 ];
   ```

   Even with that the grammar gets stuck in an infinite loop for non-trivial programs (try it with its own source). The following should clear things up a little:

   ```
   identifier_soup = !recursiveImpCpp >> +~qi::char_("(){}");
   parenthesized = '(' >> -nestedSomething >> ')';
   bracketed     = '{' >> -nestedSomething >> '}';
   nestedSomething %=  qi::raw[ -identifier_soup
       >> -parenthesized
       >> -bracketed
       >> -identifier_soup] [ qi::_pass = px::size(qi::_1) > 0 ];
   ```

   But that will still not parse e.g. `int main() { if(true) { std::cout << "Yes\n"; } else { std::cout << "No\n"; } }`). The reason is that `main(<parenthesized>){<bracketed>}` does only accept `nestedSomething` inside the brackets; that expressly prohibits the `if-else` construct...

   Let's rename `ifElseContent` to something proper (like `statement`)

   ```
   block     = '{' >> startRule >> '}';
   statement = block | singleStatement;
   ```

   and use it instead of the `bracketed`:

   ```
   nestedSomething %= qi::raw[ -identifier_soup
       >> -parenthesized
       >> -block
       >> -identifier_soup] [ qi::_pass = boost::phoenix::size(qi::_1) > 0 ];
   ```

General various notes

- you can simplify the includes, instead of wrapping them in regions to hide them
- you can simplify the rest too (see my demo)
- the grammar is going to be quite inefficient with all the negative look-aheads. Consider tokenizing or using a much more finegrained keyword detection scheme (using expectation points and or `distinct()[]` from the Qi Repository)

### Partial Demo

Applying the notes above:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbafb286772a8d87)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>

#ifdef BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
    namespace std {
        template <typename... T, typename... V>
        auto& operator<<(basic_ostream<T...>& os, vector<V...> const& v) {
            os << "{";
            for (auto& el : v) os << el << " ";
            return os;
        }
    }
#endif

namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;

/* later make this variant with all impStatementVariants -> either make this a
 * vector to have sequences on all levels or make imperativeCpp derive from
 * this

    -> typedef variant<
        recursive_wrapper<ifElseStruct>,
        recursive_wrapper<switchStruct>,
        recursive_wrapper<forStruct>,
        recursive_wrapper<whileStruct>,
        recursive_wrapper<doWhileStruct>

 *
 */
struct ifElseStruct;
typedef boost::variant<ifElseStruct, std::string> someSeqNode;

struct ifElseStruct
{
    std::string ifCond;
    std::vector<someSeqNode> ifContent;
    boost::optional<std::vector<someSeqNode>> elseContent;

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const ifElseStruct& var) {
        stream << "ifCond: " << var.ifCond << " ifContent: " << var.ifContent << std::endl << "elseContent:" << var.elseContent;
        return stream;
    }
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ifElseStruct, ifCond, ifContent, elseContent)

//GRAMMAR for flowcontrol (branching and looping)
template<typename Iterator, typename Skipper> struct imperativeGrammar :qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<someSeqNode>(), Skipper>
{
    imperativeGrammar() : imperativeGrammar::base_type(startRule)
    {
        startRule = *(recursiveImpCpp | nestedSomething); //vector<variant<ifElseStruct(), string>>
        recursiveImpCpp = ifElseNormalRule.alias() /*| switchRule | whileRule | forRule ...*/;

        //attr: ifElseStruct containing-> string, vector<someSeqNode>, optional<vector<someSeqNode>>
        ifElseNormalRule = qi::lit("if") >> '(' >> condition >> ')' >> statement >> -("else" >> statement);

        condition = *~qi::char_(")");//TODO: replace with nestedSomething rule
        block     = '{' >> startRule >> '}';
        statement = block | singleStatement;

        identifier_soup = !recursiveImpCpp >> +~qi::char_("(){}");
        parenthesized = '(' >> -nestedSomething >> ')';
        bracketed     = '{' >> -nestedSomething >> '}';
        nestedSomething %= qi::raw[ -identifier_soup
            >> -parenthesized
            >> -block
            >> -identifier_soup] [ qi::_pass = boost::phoenix::size(qi::_1) > 0 ];
        singleStatement = !recursiveImpCpp >> qi::raw[*~qi::char_(';') >> ';'];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((startRule)(ifElseNormalRule)(statement)(block)(nestedSomething)(identifier_soup)(parenthesized)(bracketed)(singleStatement))
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<someSeqNode>(), Skipper> startRule;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ifElseStruct(), Skipper> recursiveImpCpp;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ifElseStruct(), Skipper> ifElseNormalRule;

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), Skipper> condition;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<someSeqNode>(), Skipper> block, statement;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), Skipper> nestedSomething;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), Skipper> singleStatement;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> identifier_soup, parenthesized, bracketed;

    /*qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> forRule;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> switchCaseBreakRule;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> whileRule;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper> doWhileRule;*/
};

#include <fstream>

int main() {
    //std::string const input = { std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::ifstream("main.cpp").rdbuf()), {} };
    std::string const input = "int main() { if(true) { std::cout << \"Yes\\n\"; } else { std::cout << \"No\\n\"; } }";

    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    It f(input.begin()), l(input.end());

    imperativeGrammar<It, qi::space_type> p;
    std::vector<someSeqNode> rep;
    bool ok = phrase_parse(f, l, p, qi::space, rep);
    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parse success: " << rep << "\n";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failure\n";

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Parse success: {int main() { if(true) { std::cout << "Yes\n"; } else { std::cout << "No\n"; } }
```

With debug info

```xml
<startRule>
  <try>int main() { if(true</try>
  <ifElseNormalRule>
    <try>int main() { if(true</try>
    <fail/>
  </ifElseNormalRule>
  <nestedSomething>
    <try>int main() { if(true</try>
    <identifier_soup>
      <try>int main() { if(true</try>
      <ifElseNormalRule>
        <try>int main() { if(true</try>
        <fail/>
      </ifElseNormalRule>
      <success>() { if(true) { std:</success>
      <attributes>[]</attributes>
    </identifier_soup>
    <parenthesized>
      <try>() { if(true) { std:</try>
      <nestedSomething>
        <try>) { if(true) { std::</try>
        <identifier_soup>
          <try>) { if(true) { std::</try>
          <ifElseNormalRule>
            <try>) { if(true) { std::</try>
            <fail/>
          </ifElseNormalRule>
          <fail/>
        </identifier_soup>
        <parenthesized>
          <try>) { if(true) { std::</try>
          <fail/>
        </parenthesized>
        <block>
          <try>) { if(true) { std::</try>
          <fail/>
        </block>
        <identifier_soup>
          <try>) { if(true) { std::</try>
          <ifElseNormalRule>
            <try>) { if(true) { std::</try>
            <fail/>
          </ifElseNormalRule>
          <fail/>
        </identifier_soup>
        <fail/>
      </nestedSomething>
      <success> { if(true) { std::c</success>
      <attributes>[]</attributes>
    </parenthesized>
    <block>
      <try> { if(true) { std::c</try>
      <startRule>
        <try> if(true) { std::cou</try>
        <ifElseNormalRule>
          <try> if(true) { std::cou</try>
          <statement>
            <try> { std::cout << "Yes</try>
            <block>
              <try> { std::cout << "Yes</try>
              <startRule>
                <try> std::cout << "Yes\n</try>
                <ifElseNormalRule>
                  <try> std::cout << "Yes\n</try>
                  <fail/>
                </ifElseNormalRule>
                <nestedSomething>
                  <try> std::cout << "Yes\n</try>
                  <identifier_soup>
                    <try>std::cout << "Yes\n"</try>
                    <ifElseNormalRule>
                      <try>std::cout << "Yes\n"</try>
                      <fail/>
                    </ifElseNormalRule>
                    <success>} else { std::cout <</success>
                    <attributes>[]</attributes>
                  </identifier_soup>
                  <parenthesized>
                    <try>} else { std::cout <</try>
                    <fail/>
                  </parenthesized>
                  <block>
                    <try>} else { std::cout <</try>
                    <fail/>
                  </block>
                  <identifier_soup>
                    <try>} else { std::cout <</try>
                    <ifElseNormalRule>
                      <try>} else { std::cout <</try>
                      <fail/>
                    </ifElseNormalRule>
                    <fail/>
                  </identifier_soup>
                  <success>} else { std::cout <</success>
                  <attributes>[[s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", Y, e, s, \, n, ", ;,  ]]</attributes>
                </nestedSomething>
                <ifElseNormalRule>
                  <try>} else { std::cout <</try>
                  <fail/>
                </ifElseNormalRule>
                <nestedSomething>
                  <try>} else { std::cout <</try>
                  <identifier_soup>
                    <try>} else { std::cout <</try>
                    <ifElseNormalRule>
                      <try>} else { std::cout <</try>
                      <fail/>
                    </ifElseNormalRule>
                    <fail/>
                  </identifier_soup>
                  <parenthesized>
                    <try>} else { std::cout <</try>
                    <fail/>
                  </parenthesized>
                  <block>
                    <try>} else { std::cout <</try>
                    <fail/>
                  </block>
                  <identifier_soup>
                    <try>} else { std::cout <</try>
                    <ifElseNormalRule>
                      <try>} else { std::cout <</try>
                      <fail/>
                    </ifElseNormalRule>
                    <fail/>
                  </identifier_soup>
                  <fail/>
                </nestedSomething>
                <success>} else { std::cout <</success>
                <attributes>[[[s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", Y, e, s, \, n, ", ;,  ]]]</attributes>
              </startRule>
              <success> else { std::cout <<</success>
              <attributes>[[[s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", Y, e, s, \, n, ", ;,  ]]]</attributes>
            </block>
            <success> else { std::cout <<</success>
            <attributes>[[[s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", Y, e, s, \, n, ", ;,  ]]]</attributes>
          </statement>
          <statement>
            <try> { std::cout << "No\</try>
            <block>
              <try> { std::cout << "No\</try>
              <startRule>
                <try> std::cout << "No\n"</try>
                <ifElseNormalRule>
                  <try> std::cout << "No\n"</try>
                  <fail/>
                </ifElseNormalRule>
                <nestedSomething>
                  <try> std::cout << "No\n"</try>
                  <identifier_soup>
                    <try>std::cout << "No\n";</try>
                    <ifElseNormalRule>
                      <try>std::cout << "No\n";</try>
                      <fail/>
                    </ifElseNormalRule>
                    <success>} }</success>
                    <attributes>[]</attributes>
                  </identifier_soup>
                  <parenthesized>
                    <try>} }</try>
                    <fail/>
                  </parenthesized>
                  <block>
                    <try>} }</try>
                    <fail/>
                  </block>
                  <identifier_soup>
                    <try>} }</try>
                    <ifElseNormalRule>
                      <try>} }</try>
                      <fail/>
                    </ifElseNormalRule>
                    <fail/>
                  </identifier_soup>
                  <success>} }</success>
                  <attributes>[[s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", N, o, \, n, ", ;,  ]]</attributes>
                </nestedSomething>
                <ifElseNormalRule>
                  <try>} }</try>
                  <fail/>
                </ifElseNormalRule>
                <nestedSomething>
                  <try>} }</try>
                  <identifier_soup>
                    <try>} }</try>
                    <ifElseNormalRule>
                      <try>} }</try>
                      <fail/>
                    </ifElseNormalRule>
                    <fail/>
                  </identifier_soup>
                  <parenthesized>
                    <try>} }</try>
                    <fail/>
                  </parenthesized>
                  <block>
                    <try>} }</try>
                    <fail/>
                  </block>
                  <identifier_soup>
                    <try>} }</try>
                    <ifElseNormalRule>
                      <try>} }</try>
                      <fail/>
                    </ifElseNormalRule>
                    <fail/>
                  </identifier_soup>
                  <fail/>
                </nestedSomething>
                <success>} }</success>
                <attributes>[[[s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", N, o, \, n, ", ;,  ]]]</attributes>
              </startRule>
              <success> }</success>
              <attributes>[[[s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", N, o, \, n, ", ;,  ]]]</attributes>
            </block>
            <success> }</success>
            <attributes>[[[s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", N, o, \, n, ", ;,  ]]]</attributes>
          </statement>
          <success> }</success>
          <attributes>[[[t, r, u, e], [[s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", Y, e, s, \, n, ", ;,  ]], [[s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", N, o, \, n, ", ;,  ]]]]</attributes>
        </ifElseNormalRule>
        <ifElseNormalRule>
          <try> }</try>
          <fail/>
        </ifElseNormalRule>
        <nestedSomething>
          <try> }</try>
          <identifier_soup>
            <try>}</try>
            <ifElseNormalRule>
              <try>}</try>
              <fail/>
            </ifElseNormalRule>
            <fail/>
          </identifier_soup>
          <parenthesized>
            <try>}</try>
            <fail/>
          </parenthesized>
          <block>
            <try>}</try>
            <fail/>
          </block>
          <identifier_soup>
            <try>}</try>
            <ifElseNormalRule>
              <try>}</try>
              <fail/>
            </ifElseNormalRule>
            <fail/>
          </identifier_soup>
          <fail/>
        </nestedSomething>
        <success> }</success>
        <attributes>[[[[t, r, u, e], [[s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", Y, e, s, \, n, ", ;,  ]], [[s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", N, o, \, n, ", ;,  ]]]]]</attributes>
      </startRule>
      <success></success>
      <attributes>[[[[t, r, u, e], [[s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", Y, e, s, \, n, ", ;,  ]], [[s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", N, o, \, n, ", ;,  ]]]]]</attributes>
    </block>
    <identifier_soup>
      <try></try>
      <ifElseNormalRule>
        <try></try>
        <fail/>
      </ifElseNormalRule>
      <fail/>
    </identifier_soup>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[i, n, t,  , m, a, i, n, (, ),  , {,  , i, f, (, t, r, u, e, ),  , {,  , s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", Y, e, s, \, n, ", ;,  , },  , e, l, s, e,  , {,  , s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", N, o, \, n, ", ;,  , },  , }]]</attributes>
  </nestedSomething>
  <ifElseNormalRule>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
  </ifElseNormalRule>
  <nestedSomething>
    <try></try>
    <identifier_soup>
      <try></try>
      <ifElseNormalRule>
        <try></try>
        <fail/>
      </ifElseNormalRule>
      <fail/>
    </identifier_soup>
    <parenthesized>
      <try></try>
      <fail/>
    </parenthesized>
    <block>
      <try></try>
      <fail/>
    </block>
    <identifier_soup>
      <try></try>
      <ifElseNormalRule>
        <try></try>
        <fail/>
      </ifElseNormalRule>
      <fail/>
    </identifier_soup>
    <fail/>
  </nestedSomething>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[[i, n, t,  , m, a, i, n, (, ),  , {,  , i, f, (, t, r, u, e, ),  , {,  , s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", Y, e, s, \, n, ", ;,  , },  , e, l, s, e,  , {,  , s, t, d, :, :, c, o, u, t,  , <, <,  , ", N, o, \, n, ", ;,  , },  , }]]]</attributes>
</startRule>
```

### Summary/advice

If you ran the above sample [on its own source](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/683f3c1c5d64cf94) you'll notice it bails on the namespace in line 9. Though it's nice that the program completes, rather than crashing, that's not encouraging.

**You need a proper grammar**. You need to THINK about what is a statement, what is a block, what is a keyword and what is the relationship between them. Part of your confusion seems to come from conflating *expressions* with *statements*.

I'd very much consider coming up with a grammar that you 1. can work 2. you know why it will work instead of ... seemingly just trying some things to cheat your way through parsing a programming language.

Have you even considered how you'd parse `std::cout << "int main() { return 0; }";` yet?

Have you thought about macros with line-continuations?